# RasberryPi Zero W LED does not turn ON

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, led

I am new to Rasberry Pi and trying to turn on an LED . 
I am using PIN BCM 18 as output and using a Python code to run it. Tried both methods using GPIO and gpiozero. But do not see any output. I have set the GPIO pin high using  GPIO.setoutput(18,GPIO.HIGH)and measured the voltage on PIN physical pin 12 and I see 0. Its the similar condition with all the GPIO's .
I am using a 330 Ohms resistor. And if run `gpio readall` I get the below output

```
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |   IN | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 0 |  7 || 8  | 0 | IN   | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |  OUT | 1 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 0 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |  OUT | 1 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

But if I measure the voltage at PIN 18 , Physical 12, I get the voltage as 0. I connected the external power supply to my LED circuit and I see it light up. But it does not using GPIO.

Any suggestion on what might be wrong?

[image: Pi and LED connection]

Comment: You are probably connecting to the wrong pin/GPIO.  A photo may help.

Comment: I think I am connecting it to Physical pin 12 . However I have posted the picture of my connections.

Comment: The GPIO are not clear enough to be sure but that does look like pin 12.  However what are the green wires connected to?  An obvious error would be having the LED back to front.

Comment: back to front connection on LED wouldn't explain `But if I measure the voltage ... I get the voltage as 0` - a multimeter would measure ±3.3v

Comment: Longer leg of LED is connected to one end of resistor and the other end of resistor is connected to Pin 12 and the shorter leg is directly connected to Pin 6